# Hide japanese IME for specific fields in web page

Tags: css, ime

I'm developing a web application for a japanese customer. He asked if it is possible to hide the IME for specific fields in the web application.
After a web search I found the css property ime-mode which would properly do what I want but is deprecated and not supported by all browsers (especially not Chrome, which is the main browser of my customer).
I haven't found any replacement for this property.
Has anyone an idea how to prevent the ime from being shown for specific fields in a web page?

Comment: "Prevent IME" means *allowing only latin characters to be input*? FWIW you can have kana-keyboards which would result in only kana to be input without an IME and/or which would be pointless without IME…

Comment: Yes, the goal is to allow only latin characters in that specific field. The reason is, that the customer would like to create reports on this fields which is easier if therein are only latin characters. They have normal ascii keyboards and uses an ime to write japanese characters.
For example in MS Access it's possible to decide for every field how the ime behave. They know this feature and want it as well in our web application.